# apostrophe in a filename is breaking the function - js

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

The below function does not work when I add files with apostrophe in them. Can anyone suggest an alternative?

```
<a style="padding: 0px 5px;" onclick="removeFile('+file_index+','+'\''+file_name+'\''+')">
```

Comment: Yes. Don't use inline event handlers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: You may use data-attributes for your function arguments and bind the element with an event handler function and use the data attributes over there..